# Confusion with variable initialization

Tags: java

Here's a code snippet that won't compile. I get an error on the last line claiming that the dots_per_page variable wasn't initialized. This error goes away when I set it equal to a value on the first line shown. Is there something I'm overlooking? I didn't think that I would have to set it equal to a value upon declaration.

```
long dots_per_page;
if (print_type == 'T' || print_type == 't') {
dots_per_page = 5000;
}       
else if (print_type == 'I' || print_type == 'i') {
dots_per_page = 10000;
}               
else {
System.out.println("You did not provide a valid option.");
}   
System.out.println(dots_per_page);
```

Comment: Look at all your possible code paths and see which one fails to initialize the variable.

Comment: Because this is a local Java variable, you have to initialize it before you use it. However, you don't necessarily have to do that at the same time you declare it. FYI, C# also has the same rule.

Comment: This is a great place to throw an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: now are you reading in from the console? or initializing the value of print_type yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a case where `dots_per_page` never gets a value. If `print_type` is not `'T'`, `'t'`, `'I'`, or `'i'`, then `"You did not provide a valid option"` is printed and the value is not set.

If you set a default value in the first line, this case will have the default value and all is well. You can also set a different value in the last `else` block.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of these answers are saying that you can't leave a primitive type unset. That is not entirely true. You can leave a primitive type unset all day long, but you can't *use* that variable until it is set. You are using `dots_per_page` on your last line in the `system.out.println` call. If you remove that line, you will also see that your code will compile. So you have multiple options to solve this problem, either initialize your variable for all code paths, or only use that variable in the code paths where it has been initialized.

An example of the second option:

```
long dots_per_page;
if (print_type == 'T' || print_type == 't') {
dots_per_page = 5000;
System.out.println(dots_per_page);
}       
else if (print_type == 'I' || print_type == 'i') {
dots_per_page = 10000;
System.out.println(dots_per_page);
}               
else {
System.out.println("You did not provide a valid option.");
}   
//System.out.println(dots_per_page); comment out this line
```

EDIT: and a third option that just came to me: return out of your method in the else case

```
long dots_per_page;
if (print_type == 'T' || print_type == 't') {
dots_per_page = 5000;
}       
else if (print_type == 'I' || print_type == 'i') {
dots_per_page = 10000;
}               
else {
System.out.println("You did not provide a valid option.");
return;
}   
System.out.println(dots_per_page);
```

Comment: as a side note, you can compare strings using `.equalsIgnoreCase()` in this situation like so: `if(print_type.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))`

Comment: @invertigo If `print_type` was a String, the code would not compile. `'` is used for chars in Java. But your answer is good, +1.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg good point, well in that case, ignore my "side note" unless you decide to use strings

Answer (score 3):

[Java Tutorial: Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.

[image: Data type default values]

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

Do this at the beginning:

```
long dots_per_page = 0;
```

All local variables must be explicitly initialized in Java, the compiler is complaining because there's an execution path that doesn't assign a value to the variable: if the `else` condition holds, what's the value of `dots_per_page`? Alternatively, you could add this to the `else` block:

```
else {
    dots_per_page = 0;
}
```

The point is: a value must *always* be assigned to a local variable if it's going to be read, no matter what execution path is run. Only attributes have default values.

Comment: `a value must always be assigned to a local variable` - when you read it yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

If **print_type** is a String, it needs to be in double quotes, and you need to use the ".equals()" method to compare them. As mentioned, if it is a **char** your code should work correctly.

Also, if the result isn't either "I" nor "T' (or their lowercase versions), **dots_per_page** doesn't have a value at the end of the program.

```
else {
    System.out.println("You did not provide a valid option.");
    dots_per_page = -1;
};
```

Something like that (an impossible return), would show you that something went wrong.

Initializing variables that you know your program should change with a value that they shouldn't be, helps show if your program is running correctly.

Comment: `print_type` is probably char, in which case single quotes is the way to go and comparing with `==` is fine.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg you are absolutely correct, I just gave some extra info if it was useful; because the declaration of print_type wasn't included.

Answer (score 0):

dots_per_page is a [primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and as such is not allowed to be unset. just
use `long dots_per_page =0`; or `long dots_per_page = -1;` at the beginning.

the other option is to add `dots_per_page = 0;` in your `else` block.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a primitive type or not, it still needs to be set when trying to read it.

Comment: Yes but IRC *Objects* default to Null.

Comment: No, all local variables don't default to anything. If you declare an Object as a field, then they default to null. But if you specify an int as a field, it defaults to 0 (zero). All primitive types have default values when declared as a field of a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
System.out.println("You did not provide a valid option.");
}   
System.out.println(dots_per_page);
```

The coding came very close to working. There was just a small error. In your if-else statement, you print out a statement that says "You did not provide a valid option." Then, you print out dots_per_page. However, if it has gone to the else statement, it cannot print dots_per_page. I would suggest having a print statement in other areas of the if-else statement where you can be sure that you have a dots_per_page to print

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `dots_per_page` to null? With the declaration I mean.